# The only action is the trivial

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be finite group of order $m$ and $X$ be a finite set of order $n$. Show that if $m$ is a prime number greater than $n$, then the only action of G under X that is possible to define is the trivial.

Sorry but, I couldn't get any idea of resolution.

Comment: Do you know about orbits?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and where you are stuck so that we can provide help consistent with what you already know.

Comment: The only idea I had was to use the fact that:
$$ | X | \equiv | X_G | \: (mod \: m) $$
where $ X_G $ denotes the set of $ X $ elements with unit orbit.

Comment: Look at a single orbit. What possible sizes can it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful perspective is to view a group action of $G$ on a finite set $X$ has a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow S_{|X|}$, where $S_{|X|}$ is the group of permutations on $|X|$ letters (it shouldn't be too hard to show that these definitions are equivalent).

Then the claim reduces to one about the existence of a nontrivial such homomorphism. You should be able to make a claim that any nontrivial homomorphism is in fact injective, and then use something about the symmetric group $S_{|X|}$ to derive a contradiction.